# Unity WebGL Build: Why it shows only Empty Folder?

Tags: unity, webgl

i'm trying to built my game, made in Unity 2018.3, and i'm trying to built it in WebGL, but the problem is this: built was succeeded, but the Folder is still Empty, and here is the problem occured: [image: hope you can read it]

This was never happened to me before. anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Please post text from error messages instead of screenshots. It’s significantly easier to search from text which in turn makes it easier to get answers. It also makes it easier for others to find this question if they are having similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try these things:

(a) Uncheck the "Strip Engine Code" from project settings -> other settings

(b) Try to build your project outside the current Unity project

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html

Comment: Weird...it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Company Name and Product Name to **"ProductName"**.
You can do this by:

Edit => Project Settings => Player

Both of the fields will be on top of the inspector.

I do not know why this is the case, but this surely fixed my issue, and hopefully yours would too!

Cheers!